# Why is the biblatex option "useeditor=true" ignored for book articles?

Tags: biblatex

Consider the following MWE. As can be seen, the option `useeditor=true` is ignored for the `@incollection` entry, and it is in fact treated equally with `useeditor=false`. Why? And how can I make it care about it?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp]{biblatex}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{beatles1970a,
    BOOKTITLE = "Let it be (a)",
    EDITOR = "The Beatles",
    TITLE = "Maggie Mae",
    YEAR = "1970",
    PAGES = "17--18",
    OPTIONS = "useeditor=true"}
@BOOK{beatles1970b,
    TITLE = "Let it be (b)",
    EDITOR = "The Beatles",
    YEAR = "1970",
    OPTIONS = "useeditor=true"}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: In @incollection "editor" refers to the booktitle, so imho it wouldn't be correct to use it in the label of the unit. You can naturally change this.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Yes, I am aware of this conundrum. I was thinking of opening a separate question about what to do when a paper in a book doesn't have an author, but an editor. It doesn't seem as if ``biblatex`` supports this scenario out of the box, since ``editor`` always refers to the book editor in such cases.

Comment: `@incollection` is a "self-contained unit with a **distinct author**", use `@inbook` instead if you don't have an author.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer If ``@inbook`` relates to ``@book`` like ``@incollection`` relates to ``@collection`` (cf. the manual under ``2.3.1``), then this is not appropriate, since the book in question doesn't have any author(s). ``@book`` is a "single-volume book with one or more authors where the authors share credit for the work as a whole".

Comment: What exactly is the role of the 'editor'? That is, usually an editor has to have something to edit. Sometimes that is written by an author. What is the editor editing in this case?

Comment: @cfr In this case (and similar cases) the editor has collected, organized, transcribed and published one or more letters to or from a person X, typically with a preface written by the said editor. I don't think it would be correct to put that under "author", since this person didn't write any of those letters.

Comment: Isn't the author the author of the letters in that case?

Comment: @cfr Not if it's a collection of letters _to_ a person. Or any other kind of collection of stuff you can think of.

Comment: Think about it in this way: If there was a book called "Letters to George Washington in 1792", I don't think anyone would hesitate leaving the ``author`` field blank and fill in the ``editor`` field with the name of the person who edited that book. Now, what are you supposed to do when there's an article (in a journal or in a book) just like that? In those cases ``editor`` will only refer to the editor of the journal/book.

Comment: But the item in the book has an author. The book doesn't have an author as a whole, but that is just like any other @collection. If you cite a letter from the collection, somebody wrote that letter and that person surely is the author of that letter.

Comment: @cfr Yes, but you wouldn't cite or list _one_ letter in an article of letters. You'd cite the article. The bibliography is supposed to tell readers where they can find the cited information, right, and that information is in the published article. I've seen lots of references to the article in question, and I've never seen anyone put individual letters (and their dates) in the bibliography, and I would be very surprised if I ever saw that.

Comment: No idea then. I've never come across an article of that kind (and I wonder if 'article' is even the right term).

Comment: @cfr I'm sure historians come across articles like this all the time. Some of these articles I have here appear in regular academic journals. Instead of saying the usual "[Title] by [John Doe]", such articles appear in the journal issue's index as "[Title] edited by [John Doe]". Since ``biblatex`` doesn't seem to support this scenario, I'm wondering how to tweak it to accept editors of articles.

Comment: How does `biblatex-historian` handle it?

Comment: @cfr I'm not sure what you mean by "it" here, but according the the manual, ``editor`` always refers to the editor of the book/journal, never the article, cf. e.g. "``historian`` will assume that any ``editor`` that is entered is the editor of the issue, rather than the article".

Answer (score 7):

In the comments it has been discussed that `editor`, `translator` and friends for `@in` works refer to the enclosing `booktitle` and not to `title`.

We can create new names that refer to the editor, translator, ... of the `title`, we will call them `ineditor`, `intranslator`, ...

First we need a `.dbx` file with the new data mode. Then we just need to copy all the macros for `editor`, `translator` to `ineditor`, `intranslator`.
In our MWE we then only need

```
\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\usebibmacro{author/ineditor+others/intranslator+others}} %% this is an ad hoc for this particular application
```

and are good to go

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{filecontents}{innames.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{innames.dbx}[2015/11/01 more field for @in types]
\RequireBiber[3]
% new translator etc.  fields for "inner" work, that is translator of title (not booktitle) in @in...
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{ineditor, intranslator, inannotator, incommentator, inintroduction, inforeword, inafterword}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference]{ineditor, intranslator, inannotator, incommentator, inintroduction, inforeword, inafterword}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, datamodel=innames]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{beatles1970a,
    BOOKTITLE = "Let it be (a)",
    inEDITOR = {{The Beatles}},
    TITLE = "Maggie Mae",
    YEAR = "1970",
    PAGES = "17--18",
    OPTIONS = "useineditor=true"}
@BOOK{beatles1970b,
    TITLE = "Let it be (b)",
    EDITOR = {{The Beatles}},
    YEAR = "1970",}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{ineditorstrg}{%
  \printtext[ineditortype]{%
    \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
      {\ifboolexpr{
         test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
         or
         test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
       }
         {\bibstring{editors}}
         {\bibstring{editor}}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{ineditortype}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{ineditortype}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{ineditortype}}}}
         {\thefield{ineditortype}}}}}

\newbibmacro*{ineditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
     }
       {\def\abx@tempa{editors}}
       {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
     }
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{ineditortype}s}}
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{ineditortype}}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{intranslator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{intranslator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{incommentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inannotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inintroduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inforeword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inafterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext[ineditortype]{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{ineditorstrg}}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslatorstrg}{%
  \printtext[intranslatortype]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumgreater{\value{intranslator}}{1}}
      or
      test {\ifandothers{intranslator}}
    }
      {\bibstring{translators}}
      {\bibstring{translator}}}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumgreater{\value{intranslator}}{1}}
    or
    test {\ifandothers{intranslator}}
  }
    {\def\abx@tempa{translators}}
    {\def\abx@tempa{translator}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{incommentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{inannotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{inintroduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{inforeword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{inafterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}


\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseineditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{ineditor}}
  }
    {\printnames{ineditor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{ineditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{ineditor}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseintranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{intranslator}}
  }
    {\printnames{intranslator}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{intranslator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{intranslator}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{author/ineditor+others/intranslator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{author}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test \ifuseineditor
       and
       not test {\ifnameundef{ineditor}}
     }
       {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}}
       {\usebibmacro{intranslator+others}}}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditor]{ineditor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byineditorx}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditorx}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditora}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditora}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditora]{ineditora}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{ineditorb}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditorb}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditorb]{ineditorb}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{ineditorc}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditorc}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditorc]{ineditorc}%
     \newunit}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{intranslator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byintranslator]{intranslator}}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byineditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditor]{ineditor}%
     \clearname{ineditor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byineditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{byintranslator+others}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{intranslator}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byintranslator+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byintranslator]{intranslator}%
     \clearname{intranslator}%
     \newunit}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
    {\def\abx@tempa{byeditor}}
    {\edef\abx@tempa{by\thefield{ineditortype}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{intranslator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{intranslator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{incommentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inannotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inintroduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inforeword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inafterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditor}{editor}}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \def\abx@tempa{bytranslator}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{incommentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{inannotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{inintroduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{inforeword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{inafterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}
\makeatother    


\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\usebibmacro{author/ineditor+others/intranslator+others}} %% this is an ad hoc for this particular application

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image: example output]

---

Maybe you find the opposite approach more logical (especially seeing that the `bookauthor` is the `author` of the `booktitle`), so we can also pretend the `editor`, `translator`, ... fields refer to the `title` and come up with new `bookeditor`, `booktranslator`, ... for the `booktitle` work. *This approach is strictly speaking incompatible with the standard data model.*

The `.dbx`  file is slightly different and most name macros are renamed to `by...`.
For the MWE we then only need

```
\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}} %% this is an ad hoc for this particular application

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookeditor+others}}
  {\typeout{yes inbook}}{\typeout{no inbook}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookeditor+others}}
  {\typeout{yes incollection}}{\typeout{no incollection}}
```

MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\usepackage{xpatch}
\begin{filecontents}{booknames.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{booknames.dbx}[2015/11/01 more field for @in types]
\RequireBiber[3]
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{bookeditor, booktranslator, bookannotator, bookcommentator, bookintroduction, bookforeword, bookafterword}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference]{bookeditor, booktranslator, bookannotator, bookcommentator, bookintroduction, bookforeword, bookafterword}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style = authoryear-comp, datamodel=booknames]{biblatex}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@INCOLLECTION{beatles1970a,
    BOOKTITLE = "Let it be (a)",
    EDITOR = {{The Beatles}},
    bookeditor = {James Joyce},
    booktranslator = {James Joyce},
    TITLE = "Maggie Mae",
    YEAR = "1970",
    PAGES = "17--18",
    OPTIONS = "useeditor=true"}
@BOOK{beatles1970b,
    TITLE = "Let it be (b)",
    EDITOR = {{The Beatles}},
    YEAR = "1970",}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{bybookeditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookeditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{bookeditor}{bookeditor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[bybookeditor]{bookeditor}%
     \newunit}}


\newbibmacro*{bybooktranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{booktranslator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[bybooktranslator]{booktranslator}}}

\newbibmacro*{bybookeditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookeditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bybookeditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[bybookeditor]{bookeditor}%
     \clearname{bookeditor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{bybooktranslator+others}}

\newbibmacro*{bybooktranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{booktranslator}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bybooktranslator+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[bybooktranslator]{booktranslator}%
     \clearname{booktranslator}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{withbookothers}}


\newbibmacro*{bybookeditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{bookeditortype}
    {\def\abx@tempa{byeditor}}
    {\edef\abx@tempa{by\thefield{bookeditortype}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{booktranslator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{booktranslator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{bookcommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{bookcommentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{bookannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{bookannotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{bookintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{bookintroduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{bookforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{bookforeword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{bookeditor}{bookafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{bookafterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{bookeditor}{bookeditor}}}

\newbibmacro*{bybooktranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \def\abx@tempa{bytranslator}%
  \ifnamesequal{booktranslator}{bookcommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{bookcommentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{booktranslator}{bookannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{bookannotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{booktranslator}{bookintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{bookintroduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{booktranslator}{bookforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{bookforeword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{booktranslator}{bookafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{bookafterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookcommentator}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookcommentator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{withcommentator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withbookcommentator]{bookcommentator}}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookannotator}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookannotator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{withannotator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withbookannotator]{bookannotator}}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookintroduction}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookintroduction}
    {}
    {\bibstring{withintroduction}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withbookintroduction]{bookintroduction}}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookforeword}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookforeword}
    {}
    {\bibstring{withbookforeword}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withbookforeword]{bookforeword}}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookafterword}{%
  \ifnameundef{bookafterword}
    {}
    {\bibstring{withafterword}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[withbookafterword]{bookafterword}}}

\newbibmacro*{withbookothers}{%
  \usebibmacro{withbookcommentator}%
  \clearname{bookcommentator}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withbookannotator}%
  \clearname{bookannotator}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withbookintroduction}%
  \clearname{bookintroduction}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withbookforeword}%
  \clearname{bookforeword}%
  \newunit
  \usebibmacro{withbookafterword}%
  \clearname{bookafterword}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\usebibmacro{author/editor+others/translator+others}} %% this is an ad hoc for this particular application

\xpatchbibdriver{inbook}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookeditor+others}}
  {\typeout{yes inbook}}{\typeout{no inbook}}

\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byeditor+others}}
  {\usebibmacro{bybookeditor+others}}
  {\typeout{yes incollection}}{\typeout{no incollection}}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```