# Biblatex, Bibliography, and \bibnamedash for treatises published in/as articles

Tags: biblatex, biber

Usually the texts of historical authors (e.g. Aristotle, Plato) are published as books. So, the BibLaTeX-entry would be `book` with the various fields for `editor`, `introduction`, `translator`, etc. used appropriately.

Sometimes, a number of shorter treatises are published within a single book. This can be handled with BibLaTeX by using one entry `book` or `collection` for the main book and for each treatise a `bookinbook` with `crossref` to the entry of the main book. In this case, the relevant information about `editor`, `introduction`, `translator` must be put in the field `Titleaddon` by using, for example: `\bibstring{byeditortrcoin} John Doe`. -- At least this is the solution I am using, because I could not find a better way to deal with these. But that actually seems fine.

Sometimes, however, a shorter treatise is published in form of an article. The issue is that it is no good solution to have them simply as an `article` in the `bib`-file, because then whenever the title of that treatise is quoted, it is in quotation marks (as a title of an `article` usually is). Titles of treatises, however, should be in *italics* (just as all the other treatises published as `book` are `bookinbook`). So, I needed a solution for this, and I also found one, but now I also found an issue with that solution. My solution so far is to have the following BibLaTeX entries:

```
@article{wisnovsky:menn:2012,
    Author = {Stephen Menn and Robert Wisnovsky},
    Journaltitle = {Mideo},
    Options = {skipbib=true},
    Pages = {73--96},
    Title = {Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī\subtitlepunct \mkbibemph{On the Four Scientific Questions Concerning the Three Kinds of Existence}},
    Volume = {29},
    Year = {2012}}

@book{yahya:wisnovsky:menn:2012,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Keywords = {Primary Source},
    Title = {Maqāla fī l-buḥūṯ al-ʿilmiyya al-arbaʿa ʿan aṣnāf al-wuǧūd al-ṯalāṯa al-ilāhī wa-l-ṭabīʿī wa-l-manṭiqī},
    Titleaddon = {\bibstring{byeditortrin} \fullcite{wisnovsky:menn:2012}}}
```

As you can see, the second entry is the treatise as a `book`, so its title will be in italics. The information about its `editor`, `introduction`, `translator` is in the fiel `Titleaddon` which also contains a `\fullcite` to add the rest of the information by using all the information in the first entry which is the normal entry for the original `article` (NB: the article has a different title than the treatise which it contains!). I made sure that the first entry does *not* show up in the bibliography by using the option `Options = {skipbib=true}`.

The result is nice. It is the following:

> Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī. *Maqāla fī l-buḥūṯ al-ʿilmiyya al-arbaʿa ʿan aṣnāf al-wuǧūd al-ṯalāṯa al-ilāhī wa-l-ṭabīʿī wa-l-manṭiqī*. Edited and translated, with an introduction, by Stephen Menn and Robert Wisnovsky. “Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī. On the Four Scientific Questions Concerning the Three Kinds of Existence”. In: *Mideo* 29 (2012), 73–96.

Perfect. -- BUT: In the bibliography, I get the following issue. Repeated instance of the same author name or editor name is replaced by a `\bibnamedash`. But now, because I invoke in the `Titleaddon` field a `\fullcite` command, I get the following result:

> **Bibliography**
>
> ...
>
> Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī. *Book One*. Information blabla.
>
> ----------. *Book Two*. Information blabla.
>
> ----------. *Maqāla fī l-buḥūṯ al-ʿilmiyya al-arbaʿa ʿan aṣnāf al-wuǧūd al-ṯalāṯa al-ilāhī wa-l-ṭabīʿī wa-l-manṭiqī*. Edited and translated, with an introduction, by Stephen Menn and Robert Wisnovsky. “Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī. On the Four Scientific Questions Concerning the Three Kinds of Existence”. In: *Mideo* 29 (2012), 73–96. [this is my special entry]
>
> Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī. *Book Three*. Information blabla.
>
> ----------. *Book Four*. Information blabla.
>
> ...

So, the authorname of *Book Three* is repeated because -- I guess -- I invoked the `\fullcite` command which has its own author/editor name information.

Surely I used this workaround, because I did not know of a better way for how to deal with treatises published as articles (or as parts of books). What I would like to know now is:

1. Is there a better way to deal with these kinds of publications which keeps all my desired output formatting but which avoids the bibliography issue?
2. Or alternatively: how can I avoid the repeated authorname in the Bibliography?

Regarding #2: I'd be also happy with a dirty workaround, for example manually "overwriting" the author/editor information that governs the `\bibnamedash` stuff, such as having the following imaginary solution where I edit the `titleaddon` field in my second BibLaTeX entry thusly:

```
`Titleaddon = {\bibstring{byeditortrin} \fullcite{wisnovsky:menn:2012}\bibnamedashauthoreditorinfo{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}}`
```

Any ideas?

### MWE

```
%!TEX TS-program = lualatexmk
\documentclass{scrbook}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[Ligatures=TeX]{Linux Libertine O}
\usepackage[backend=biber,style=authortitle-comp,abbreviate=false,]{biblatex}
\renewcommand*{\bibnamedash}{\rule[0.48ex]{3em}{0.14ex}\labelnamepunct\space}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{wisnovsky:menn:2012,
    Author = {Stephen Menn and Robert Wisnovsky},
    Journaltitle = {Mideo},
    Options = {skipbib=true},
    Pages = {73--96},
    Title = {Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī\subtitlepunct \mkbibemph{On the Four Scientific Questions Concerning the Three Kinds of Existence}},
    Volume = {29},
    Year = {2012}}
@bookinbook{yahyaibnadi:ibnabisaid:1988,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Crossref = {yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988},
    Pages = {314--336},
    Title = {Kitāb Aǧwiba Bišr al-Yahūdī ʿan masāʾilihī}}
@book{yahya:wisnovsky:menn:2012,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Title = {Maqāla fī l-buḥūṯ al-ʿilmiyya al-arbaʿa ʿan aṣnāf al-wuǧūd al-ṯalāṯa al-ilāhī wa-l-ṭabīʿī wa-l-manṭiqī},
    Titleaddon = {\bibstring{byeditortrin} \fullcite{wisnovsky:menn:2012}}}
@bookinbook{yahyaibnadi:mawjudat:1988,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Crossref = {yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988},
    Pages = {266--274},
    Title = {Maqāla fī l-mawǧūdāt}}
@bookinbook{yahyaibnadi:alumuralamma:1988,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Crossref = {yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988},
    Pages = {148--159},
    Title = {Maqāla fī tabyīn wuǧūd al-umūr al-ʿāmmiyya wa-l-naḥw allaḏī ʿalayhi takūnu maḥmūla wa-l-naḥw allaḏī taḫruǧu bihī min an takūna maḥmūla}}
@book{yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988,
    Annotator = {Saḥbān Ḫalīfāt},
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Editor = {Saḥbān Ḫalīfāt},
    Introduction = {Saḥbān Ḫalīfāt},
    Location = {Amman},
    Publisher = {al-Ǧāmiʿa al-Urduniyya},
    Series = {Manšūrāt al-Ǧāmiʿa al-Urduniyya},
    Title = {Maqālāt Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī al-falsafiyya},
    Year = {1988}}
@bookinbook{yahyaibnadi:gins:madda:1988,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Crossref = {yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988},
    Pages = {280--292},
    Title = {Šarḥ maʿānī maqālat al-Iskandar al-Afrūdīsī fī l-farq bayna al-ǧins wa-l-mādda}}
\end{filecontents}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}
\nocite{wisnovsky:menn:2012,yahyaibnadi:ibnabisaid:1988,yahya:wisnovsky:menn:2012,yahyaibnadi:mawjudat:1988,yahyaibnadi:alumuralamma:1988,yahyaibnadi:khalifat:1988,yahyaibnadi:gins:madda:1988}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe Maïeul's [`biblatex-bookinarticle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bookinarticle) can help you, it provides `@bookinarticle`, which could be what you need.

Comment: I just did a short test with `@bookinarticle` and got (as far as I could see - I have no idea how exactly the output should look) quite pleasing results. If you need any help with getting things of the ground just ping me.

Comment: I don't understand why you use the `titleaddon` for that information in the `bookinbook` case. Surely it is better to use the dedicated fields intended for this? I can't see why `titleaddon` is needed. (Which is to say, I've got entries which sound like those you describe and I've never needed to resort to this.) Books in articles is a different problem, though.

Comment: @cfr : I need the information about, for example, the `translator` to appear immediately after the title of the *treatise* (because the translator is a translator of the *treatise* and not of the *book* in which the treatise was published). If I then use the "dedicated fields", BibLaTeX sorts the information to the *book*, and not to the treatise. In short: I nedd it to be like this: `Author. *Title*. Translated by John Doe. In: *Booktitle*. Edited by Albert Einstein. Press. Year.` **and not:** `Author. *Title*. In: *Booktitle*. Edited by Albert Einstein. Translated by John Doe. Press. Year.`

Comment: With `bookinbook` and friends `translator`s etc. refer to the `booktitle` and not the `title`, see [Why is the biblatex option “useeditor=true” ignored for book articles?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216369/35864) for a solution. Did you get `biblatex-bookinarticle` to work?

Comment: @moewe : Yes, I did a biref check yesterday and it seemed fine. will look further into it later today (and will have to edit a whole bunch of entries in my bib-file...). One question I do have: why is something like this not simply implemented into `biblatex`? It is so comprehensive, why not just adding these two bib-types?

Comment: @ClintEastwood I can only speculate here, but `biblatex` tried to reproduce the types supported by BibTeX, of which `@bookinarticle` isn't one. (Plus, LaTeX package development often has a bias towards maths and natural sciences, in which `@bookinarticle` isn't that common, I'd say.)

Comment: @moewe : I don't quite get what Maïeul wrote under **Customization**. In addition to that, the style prints the term "volume" before the volume number of an article, while in all the usual articles that term is not printed (an in Maïeul's example in the documentation it is not printed either).

Comment: @moewe But it is odd that `translator` is assumed to refer to the `maintitle` rather than the `title` isn't it?

Comment: What about `\DeclareFieldFormat[bookinarticle]{volume}{#1}` (should probably be set automatically in the package)? The *customisation* section just says that `@bookinarticle` and `@bookinincollection` are implemented more or less analogous to what the standard styles do to `@inbook` and friends.

Comment: @cfr Mhhhh, yes. Maybe, I can think ob both cases: A collection that is in its entirety translated by the same person and one containing sources translated by different people. So no matter what you do, it will go wrong sooner or later. And the way it is currently implemented `translator` and `editor` always refer to the same thing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Maïeul](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/7712/ma%C3%AFeul)'s [`biblatex-bookinarticle`](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/biblatex-bookinarticle) package adds support of the two new entry types `@bookinarticle` and `@bookinincollection` to `biblatex`.

`@bookinarticle` is a very good fit for what you have

```
@bookinarticle{yahya:wisnovsky:menn:2012,
    Author = {{Yaḥyā ibn ʿAdī}},
    Title = {Maqāla fī l-buḥūṯ al-ʿilmiyya al-arbaʿa ʿan aṣnāf al-wuǧūd al-ṯalāṯa al-ilāhī wa-l-ṭabīʿī wa-l-manṭiqī},
    crossref =  {wisnovsky:menn:2012},
}
```

---

While you wait for the updated version of the package that brings the output slightly more in line with `@article` (see [issue #4 at github](https://github.com/maieul/biblatex-bookinarticle/issues/4)) you might also want to add the lines (a copy of the definitions for `@article` from `biblatex.def`)

```
\DeclareFieldFormat[inarticle,bookinarticle]{series}{% series of a journal
  \ifinteger{#1}
    {\mkbibordseries{#1}~\bibstring{jourser}}
    {\ifbibstring{#1}{\bibstring{#1}}{#1}}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[inarticle,bookinarticle]{volume}{#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[inarticle,bookinarticle]{number}{#1}% number of a journal
```

to your preamble.

Comment: I have send on CTAN the new version of the package with these definitions included.