# Biblatex: how to put translator before booktitle (@incollection)?

Tags: biblatex

I've been using the `biblatex-dw` citation style with footnotes and several improvements to it. My question is: how can I generate footnotes from the `@incollection` entry so that the translator is put directly after the title of the article, not after the book title?

Below there is an example of my preamble:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,pdftex]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french,polish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\DeclareQuoteAlias{croatian}{polish}

\usepackage[
style=footnote-dw,
autopunct=false,
sorting=nty,
abbreviate = true,
idembibformat = dash,
nopublisher = false,
pageref = false,
backend=biber]{biblatex}

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{nr~#1}% number of a journal

\newbibmacro*{in:}{%
    \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
            \bibstring{in}\addcolon}\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
    \printfield{volume}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{number}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
    \usebibmacro{journal}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
        \printfield{series}%
        \setunit{\addspace}}%
    \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
    \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
    \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
    \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
    \usebibmacro{issue}%
    \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
    \printfield{issue}%
    \setunit*{\addspace}%
    \usebibmacro{date}%
    \newunit}

\addbibresource{thesis.bib}

\begin{document}
Tytuł dokumentu\cite{jameson_postmodernizm_1996}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

And the .bib file:

```
@incollection{jameson_postmodernizm_1996,
    location = {Kraków},
    title = {Postmodernizm i społeczeństwo konsumpcyjne},
    booktitle = {Postmodernizm. Antologia przekładów},
    publisher = {Wydawnictwo Baran i Suszczyński},
    author = {Jameson, Fredric},
    editor = {Nycz, Ryszard},
    translator = {Czapliński, Przemysław},
    date = {1996}
```

This is the following output:
[image]

How can I edit the bbx or cbx files so that the translator field would be before the book title (the translation refers only to one article in a collection)?

[image]

Comment: The `translator` and `editor` of an `@incollection` refer to the enclosing work (the `booktitle`) and not to the `title`, so it is only natural that they should appear after the `booktitle` and not directly after the `title`. In https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216369/35864 there is a s solution for a new `intranslator` that would be printed after the `title`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is similar to [Why is the biblatex option "useeditor=true" ignored for book articles?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/216369/35864). The problem is that `translator` and `editor` refer to `booktitle` in `@in...` works and not to `title`. You can introduce the new names `ineditor` and `instranslator` that refer to the `title`. It requires a bit of machinery, but gets you there in the end

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{report}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[english,french,polish]{babel}
\usepackage{csquotes}

%\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@incollection{jameson_postmodernizm_1996,
  location     = {Kraków},
  title        = {Postmodernizm i społeczeństwo konsumpcyjne},
  booktitle    = {Postmodernizm. Antologia przekładów},
  publisher    = {Wydawnictwo Baran i Suszczyński},
  author       = {Jameson, Fredric},
  editor       = {Nycz, Ryszard},
  intranslator = {Czapliński, Przemysław},
  date         = {1996},
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{innames.dbx}
\ProvidesFile{innames.dbx}[2018/05/09 more names for @in types]
\RequireBiber[3]
% new translator etc. fields for "inner" work, that is translator of title (not booktitle) in @in...
\DeclareDatamodelFields[type=list,datatype=name]{ineditor, ineditora, ineditorb, ineditorc, intranslator, intranslator, inannotator, incommentator, inintroduction, inforeword, inafterword}
\DeclareDatamodelEntryfields[inbook,incollection,inproceedings,inreference]{ineditor, ineditora, ineditorb, ineditorc, intranslator, inannotator, incommentator, inintroduction, inforeword, inafterword}
\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[
  backend=biber,
  datamodel=innames,
  style=footnote-dw,
  autopunct=false,
  sorting=nty,
  abbreviate = true,
  idembibformat = dash,
  nopublisher = false,
  pageref = false,
]{biblatex}

\makeatletter
\newbibmacro*{ineditorstrg}{%
  \printtext[ineditortype]{%
    \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
      {\ifboolexpr{
         test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
         or
         test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
       }
         {\bibstring{editors}}
         {\bibstring{editor}}}
      {\ifbibxstring{\thefield{ineditortype}}
         {\ifboolexpr{
            test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
            or
            test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
          }
            {\bibstring{\thefield{ineditortype}s}}
            {\bibstring{\thefield{ineditortype}}}}
         {\thefield{ineditortype}}}}}

\newbibmacro*{ineditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
     }
       {\def\abx@tempa{editors}}
       {\def\abx@tempa{editor}}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test {\ifnumgreater{\value{ineditor}}{1}}
       or
       test {\ifandothers{ineditor}}
     }
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{ineditortype}s}}
       {\edef\abx@tempa{\thefield{ineditortype}}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{intranslator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{intranslator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{incommentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inannotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inintroduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inforeword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inafterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext[ineditortype]{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{ineditorstrg}}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslatorstrg}{%
  \printtext[intranslatortype]{%
    \ifboolexpr{
      test {\ifnumgreater{\value{intranslator}}{1}}
      or
      test {\ifandothers{intranslator}}
    }
      {\bibstring{translators}}
      {\bibstring{translator}}}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test {\ifnumgreater{\value{intranslator}}{1}}
    or
    test {\ifandothers{intranslator}}
  }
    {\def\abx@tempa{translators}}
    {\def\abx@tempa{translator}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{incommentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{inannotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{inintroduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{inforeword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{inafterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}


\newbibmacro*{ineditor+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseineditor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{ineditor}}
  }
    {\printnames{ineditor}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{ineditor+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{ineditor}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{intranslator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseintranslator
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{intranslator}}
  }
    {\printnames{intranslator}%
     \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
     \usebibmacro{intranslator+othersstrg}%
     \clearname{intranslator}}
    {}}

\newbibmacro*{author/ineditor+others/intranslator+others}{%
  \ifboolexpr{
    test \ifuseauthor
    and
    not test {\ifnameundef{author}}
  }
    {\usebibmacro{author}}
    {\ifboolexpr{
       test \ifuseineditor
       and
       not test {\ifnameundef{ineditor}}
     }
       {\usebibmacro{ineditor+others}}
       {\usebibmacro{intranslator+others}}}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditor}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditor]{ineditor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byineditorx}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditorx}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditora}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditora}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditora]{ineditora}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{ineditorb}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditorb}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditorb]{ineditorb}%
     \newunit}%
  \ifnameundef{ineditorc}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditorc}{editor}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditorc]{ineditorc}%
     \newunit}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator}{%
  \ifnameundef{intranslator}
    {}
    {\bibstring{bytranslator}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byintranslator]{intranslator}}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{ineditor}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byineditor+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byineditor]{ineditor}%
     \clearname{ineditor}%
     \newunit}%
  \usebibmacro{byineditorx}%
  \usebibmacro{byintranslator+others}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator+others}{%
  \ifnameundef{intranslator}
    {}
    {\usebibmacro{byintranslator+othersstrg}%
     \setunit{\addspace}%
     \printnames[byintranslator]{intranslator}%
     \clearname{intranslator}%
     \newunit}}

\newbibmacro*{byineditor+othersstrg}{%
  \iffieldundef{ineditortype}
    {\def\abx@tempa{byeditor}}
    {\edef\abx@tempa{by\thefield{ineditortype}}}%
  \let\abx@tempb=\empty
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{intranslator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{tr}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{intranslator}}}
    {}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{incommentator}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inannotator}}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inintroduction}}}
    {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inforeword}}}
       {\ifnamesequal{ineditor}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \appto\abx@tempb{\clearname{inafterword}}}
          {}}}%
  \ifbibxstring{\abx@tempa}
    {\printtext{\bibstring{\abx@tempa}}\abx@tempb}
    {\usebibmacro{bytypestrg}{ineditor}{editor}}}

\newbibmacro*{byintranslator+othersstrg}{%
  \def\abx@tempa{bytranslator}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{incommentator}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{co}%
     \clearname{incommentator}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inannotator}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{an}%
        \clearname{inannotator}}
       {}}%
  \ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inintroduction}
    {\appto\abx@tempa{in}%
     \clearname{inintroduction}}
    {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inforeword}
       {\appto\abx@tempa{fo}%
        \clearname{foreword}}
       {\ifnamesequal{intranslator}{inafterword}
          {\appto\abx@tempa{af}%
           \clearname{afterword}}
          {}}}%
  \bibstring{\abx@tempa}}
\makeatother

\renewbibmacro*{author/translator+others}{\usebibmacro{author/ineditor+others/intranslator+others}} %% this is an ad hoc for this particular application

\renewcommand*{\newunitpunct}{\addcomma\space}
\renewbibmacro*{in:}{}

\renewcommand{\multinamedelim}{\addcomma\space}

\DeclareFieldFormat{title}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{booktitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{citetitle}{\mkbibemph{#1}}
\DeclareFieldFormat{journaltitle}{\mkbibquote{#1\isdot}}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{volume}{\bibstring{jourvol}~#1}% volume of a journal
\DeclareFieldFormat[article,periodical]{number}{nr~#1}% number of a journal

\usepackage{xpatch}
\xpatchbibdriver{incollection}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}}
  {\usebibmacro{byauthor}%
   \newunit
   \usebibmacro{byineditor+others}}
  {}{}

\renewbibmacro*{in:}{%
  \ifentrytype{article}
    {}
    {\printtext[brackets]{%
       \bibstring{in}\addcolon}\space}}

\renewbibmacro*{volume+number+eid}{%
  \printfield{volume}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{number}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \printfield{eid}}

\renewbibmacro*{journal+issuetitle}{%
  \usebibmacro{journal}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \iffieldundef{series}
    {}
    {\newunit
     \printfield{series}%
     \setunit{\addspace}}%
  \usebibmacro{issue+date}%
  \setunit{\addcomma\space}%
  \usebibmacro{volume+number+eid}%
  \setunit{\addcolon\space}%
  \usebibmacro{issue}%
  \newunit}

\renewbibmacro*{issue+date}{%
  \printfield{issue}%
  \setunit*{\addspace}%
  \usebibmacro{date}%
  \newunit}

\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\addbibresource{biblatex-examples.bib}

\begin{document}
Tytuł dokumentu\cite{jameson_postmodernizm_1996}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]